# Looking for some help understanding some prepare for segue and optionals code. - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, option-type

I posted a question on my profile last week wondering how to transfer information from one table controller to another using the prepare for segue function.  I have a basic understanding of how to set up the controllers themselves, but as my question infers, I am looking for some help to understand some specifics of the code presented.

Below are just snippets of the code that are most important (keep in mind, these are from a table controller.
In the first controller, I have

```
    var countries = ["American", "Asian", "Italian"]
    var items = [["Mcdonalds", "BurgerKing", "Big Boy"], ["PFChangs", "China One Buffet"], ["Pizza House", "Pizza Hit", "Olive Garden", "Maggianos"]]

 if (segue.identifier == "segueone")
    {
        let cellIndexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
        if  let unwrappedCellindexPath = cellIndexPath
        {
            var nextVC = (segue.destinationViewController as TableTwo)
            nextVC.items = items[unwrappedCellindexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

and on the second table controller I have

```
 var items: [String]?
```

So my questions are as follows.
1."let cellIndexPath = self.table!.indexpathforCell(sender as UITableViewCell".  I understand that I am setting cellIndexPath, a constant, equal the indexPathForCell, which is the index path of the cell in the table, however why do I need the "!" when the value (to my current belief) will always return a value and never a nil?

2. what is the difference between indexPath and indexPath.row? or are they the same?
3. Is there another way to achieve the results of the if statement?  I've never seen an "If" and "let" constant situation before.
4. Along the lines of question 2, why do I need to add ".row" to the end of "unwrappedcellindexpath" when it is not mentioned that way in the "if" statement?  Why do i need to add it now?
5. Just like 1, why does the "[string]" require a "?" after?

I apologize for the questions and I am aware of Apple's developer website, but I usually do better with  more personal responses... as in, answer phrased in a different way.

Regardless, thanks for any help!

Comment: You should read the introduction to Swift book. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/  It's a quick read and will answer most of your questions better than someone here will.

Comment: ill take a read.  Conceptually (and learning eagerness), I would still appreciate input for 2 and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First (unnumbered) question: You need the "!" because your self.table is declared as an "optional". That means that it could be a valid value, or it could be nil. The compiler won't let you dereference an optional without "unwrapping" it.

The "!" is a "forced unwrap". This means "dammit, I know this won't be nil. Just let me use it."

If the variable/constant IS nil at runtime, you crash on a forced unwrap.

Another option is something called "optional binding". For that you use the "if let" syntax. That might look something like this:

```
if let requiredObject = optional
{
  //code using requiredObject.
}
else
{
  //the optional was nil
}
```

It checks to see if the optional is nil. If it is, it stops. If it's not, it copies the optional to a required constant, and then executes the code inside the braces. You can then use the new "requiredObject" constant inside the braces and know that it will always be valid.

#2. an `NSIndexPath` is an NSObject that contains multiple values. They are intended to be multi-purpose, and contain variable numbers of values. In iOS I've never seen it used for anything other than a section and a row. The iOS flavor of `NSIndexPath` has properties `section` and `row` (which are integers). For a single section tableview, you just use `indexPath.row` to get the cell number.

#3. See #1. the "if let" optional binding lets you forget about exclamation points. If the variable isn't nil, the code inside the braces runs, and the new constant is guaranteed not to be nil. The alternative is to use `if variable? != nil` everywhere, or simply `variable!" if you are sure it won't be nil.

#4. See #2.

#5: The code `var items: [String]?`

Means "define an **optional** variable called items, of type array to string. It will either point to a valid array, or it might be nil.

You really need to read Apple's Swift language iBook. I read it over the weekend. It explains all this stuff.

Comment: I suppose I can only get so far from reading and copying code found in course lectures... I'll definitely take a look, since it seems I need to haha.   Regardless, thank you, Duncan for the more humanistic explanation of these terms.  And just one more question, every time I transfer information using the prepare for segue function, will I need to use optionals?  Is that just how swift works?

Comment: Well... Its pretty common to use optionals for properties that get set from outside, since until they DO get set, they are nil.